# How I get product options block in catalog

Tags: magento, product

I did an quick view in product catalog (list.phtml) using Magento 1.7, but I'm unable to get the FULL product options block so that it is identical to the product page (showing select, radio button, select multiple, etc.). Can someone help me?

*Sorry for my bad English.

I tried put the view.phtml' code, but this don't work.
I also tried some tutorials that I found on google, but what worked converted all options in select, but I need to get entire block.

```
...
<?php if (!$this->hasOptions()):?>
    <div class="add-to-box">
        <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
            <?php if( $this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow() || $_compareUrl=$this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddUrl($_product)): ?>
                <span class="or"><?php echo $this->__('OR') ?></span>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>


<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('other');?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>
<?php endif;?>
...
```

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried so we can see where you may have gone wrong?

Comment: I edited the question by entering the code. Can anyone else help me?